# PHP getting duplicate JSON Array

Tags: php, json

I have got the JSON array output, but it contains duplicate values 
Below you can see the duplicate json_array in 0th index...
I don't know, what's the problem,
need suggestion and why...? Thanks in advance

**My output:**

```
[{"gallery_url":"fdkgvdjvb.img"}][{"gallery_url":"fdkgvdjvb.img"},{"gallery_url":"gdfgh.mp4"}]
```

**Required output:**

```
[{"gallery_url":"fdkgvdjvb.img"},{"gallery_url":"gdfgh.mp4"}]
```

**My code:**

```
<?php
$json = array();
$gallery=$_GET['gallery'];



        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","allluser","password4");
    if($con)
    {
    //echo "connected";
    }
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($con,'jumeirah_db');
    if($db_select)
    {
    //echo "db selected";
    }
    $user_type=$_GET['user_type'];
    $image=mysqli_query($con,"Select gallery_url from ju_gallery where user_type='$user_type'");
if ($image) {


while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image)) {
    $json[] = $r;
    print json_encode($json);
}
}   
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Take out the `print json_encode($json);` statement from inside your `while` loop and put it outside.

Comment: Yes it works,,,Thanks man,,,But why this happens.

Comment: That is simple, @arun. You're printing the JSON encoded value for each row. You only need the JSON representation of the **entire array**.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image)) {
    $json[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($json);
```

this should print your expected result.

Your database actually returns two results that will cause exactly two iterations in your while loop.

the first iteration adds $r to your $json array. now the array has one element and you print it out.

the second iteration adds another $r to your $json array which now has TWO elements.
the second `print` outputs your expected result.

the "duplication" is caused by the print INSIDE your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the json_encode statement.

```
<?php
$json = array();
$gallery=$_GET['gallery'];

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","allluser","password4");
    if($con)
    {
    //echo "connected";
    }
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($con,'jumeirah_db');
    if($db_select)
    {
    //echo "db selected";
    }
    $user_type=$_GET['user_type'];
    $image=mysqli_query($con,"Select gallery_url from ju_gallery where user_type='$user_type'");
if ($image) {


while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image)) {
    $json[] = $r;
}
 print json_encode($json);
}   
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```